# What is the java code equivalent of this hbase command

Tags: java, hbase

I need to know how create partitioned table in Hbase from java. Under is the command I use in shell but i need the Java equivalent instructions because I want to create tables in dynamically mode.

`create 'DATABASE_NAMEB:TABLE_NAME','FAMILY_NAME', SPLITS => ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','A','B','C','D','E','F','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','00','0A','0B','0C','0D','0E','0F' ]`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this site
https://www.programmersought.com/article/55225122809/

```
HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);
HTableDescriptor tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tablename);
tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("cf1"));
       
byte[][] splitKeys = {
    Bytes.toBytes("10"),
    Bytes.toBytes("20"),
    Bytes.toBytes("30")
};
 
admin.createTable(tableDesc, splitKeys);
admin.close();
```